# Using an inner class of a generic class

Tags: java, hadoop

This is a generic Java question though it's specifically causing me pain due to a dependency on Hadoop 2.6.

The external code that I'm trying to work with looks like:

```
package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce;

public class Reducer<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT> {

  public abstract class  Context 
    implements ReduceContext<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT> {
  }
}
```

And my own code looks like

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;

public class MyReducerTest {

    @Mock
    private Context context;
}
```

I get a compiler warning with this code that I can't seem to get rid of short of suppressing it.

```
Reducer.Context is a raw type. References to generic type
  Reducer<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>.Context should be parameterized
```

Every time I try to find out what to do, the answers seem to revolve around changing the structure of the nested class to use class parameters differently. But changing Hadoop's code is not an option (nor is upgrading from 2.6 due to team constraints).

I've tried

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<?,?,?,?>.Context;
```

and

```
public class MyReducerTest {    
    @Mock
    private Context<?,?,?,?> context;
}
```

but those cause compiler errors. I can suppress the warning or just try to ignore it, but those options are bad for their own reasons.

So what does Java want me to do here?

Comment: Why is `Context` an inner class?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Context` class is an inner class. Any `Context` value is therefore related to an instance of its enclosing type, `Reducer`. That relation includes generic type parameters.

The non raw type expression is

```
@Mock
private Reducer<?, ?, ?, ?>.Context context;
```

But you should probably parameterize it appropriately. If this was not your intention (to link them this way), make `Context` `static` or declare it as a top level class.

<sub>Ignore that for [`Reducer`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.java#L129) since it's part of the Hadoop code base.</sub>